# CSS: Absolute div and media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive, absolute

I assume this has been posted before and I apologize in advance, I'm afraid I didn't find the solution.

My issue: I have a design with two divs, one must be transparent on top of the other. I was able to achieve that with div 1: position relative and div 2: position absolute, z-index: 1. However the page must be responsive and I cannot change the size of the absolute div.

Somehow, I need to find a way to make the transparent absolute div responsive with media query.

Basically, this is the desired design:

```css
.main {
display: flex;
}
.content {
height: 200px;
padding-left: 36px;
padding-right: 100px;
position: relative;
flex: 1;
background-color: lightblue;
}

.visual {
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
right: 24px;
background-color:rgba(106, 132, 226, 0.1);
```

```html
  <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
         <h1 id="header">title</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="description">
                <h3 id="description-text">Text</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="visual">
            <h3>Transparent div</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried.

Comment: it's doable. but please always share the code in a snippet

Comment: For now, it is responsive itself.

Comment: @MeghnaBhuptani I need to apply specific sizes to the transparent div with media queries, but at the moment it's staying the same size no matter what

Comment: You can consider these breakpoints for responsive layout and give specific sizes to specific breakpoints. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/

Answer (score 1):

change width to percent instead of px

and for media query, you must set width for each query.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  }

  .content {
  height: 200px;
  padding-left: 36px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
  }
  
  .visual {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 24px;
  background-color:rgba(106, 132, 226, 0.1);
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .visual {
      width: 400px;
    }

  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
     <h1 id="header">title</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="description">
            <h3 id="description-text">Text</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="visual">
          <h3>Transparent div</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That would have worked but for this particular page, I am given specific px sizes for each breakpoint

Comment: px will work too, just set it for each media query. I will change code to px

Comment: I just changed to px and it works and responsive for me.

Comment: Hm I must be doing something wrong, it's not changing sizes for me...

"@media screen and (min-width: 1220px) {
    .content {
        width: 540px;
    }

    .visual {
        width: 476px;
    }
}"

Comment: @pseudodejapris - the procedure is to tick the answer when it works for you.